# Transparent triangle with fixed background

Tags: html, css

When pages have fixed background scrolling (not parallax), is there a way to implement a triangle in the second row but have it transparent so that it shows the fixed background?

i.e.

```
-------------------------
this is fixed background


-----------   -----------
           \ /

second row solid colour
-------------------------
```

The second row would have a solid colour except the triangle where the background is the fixed image background. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean an overlay with a cutout (window) showing what's underneath? I don't know what you're asking is very clear.

Comment: I think of making 3 inline divs, where the middle is a transparent .png file...

Comment: Please show us the code you have and explain what you need using a wireframe or an image. As far as I understood, you're looking to position a triangle image over another HTML element. This can be done using CSS `z-index:999; position:absolute; top:...; left:...;`. You also need to give a `position:relative` to the parent container.

Comment: This demonstrates using several elements to create a "knockout": http://jsfiddle.net/tbe2jLuo/

Comment: Here is a beginning, but not yet finished:  http://jsfiddle.net/bbredewold/e69hzhpz/1/

Comment: if the background where the arrow will be cut out is plain, yes. Otherwise, I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tidir/1/

#### http://jsbin.com/tidir/1/edit

[image]

**HTML**

```
<section class="featurette"></section>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,html {background:#222;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}

.featurette {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/700/400/cats/);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.featurette:before,
.featurette:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
    transform: skew(40deg);
    background: #222;
}
.featurette:after {
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 -40px 0 0;
    transform: skew(-40deg);
}


.featurette:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

/* demo only */
body {height:2000px;}
```